# Can a Lipschitz continuous function be linear almost everywhere but not linear everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Can a Lipschitz continuous function be linear almost everywhere but not linear everywhere?

(:sorry for ambiguity) The almost everywhere here is defined as:

Let $f:\mathbb R^k\to\mathbb R$. $\nabla f(x)=v$ almost surely where $v$ is a constant.

That is $\nexists$ open set $U\subseteq dom(x)$ s.t. $\nabla f(x)\neq v \ \forall x\in U.$

My intuition is "no" but I don't know how to prove it. It is not a homework.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance: What is a “almost linear” function?

Comment: How do you define *almost linear everywhere*?

Comment: The issue is never whether a question is homework, or not.  The issue with this post is that you include **no context**.

Comment: So we are given $f$ is Lipschitz and $\nabla f = v$ a.e.?

Comment: With usual definition of almost everywhere the answer is 'no'. Your definition is very strange. What is the source of this definition?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy . Your deleted A was almost there. Just  replace the Cantor set $C$ with a "fat Cantor set".

Comment: So you mean “linear almost everywhere", not "almost linear everywhere"?

Comment: The usual meaning of "almost everwhere " is "except on a set of Lebesgue measure $0$". What you have asked for is "except on a set with empty interior" , which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S\subset [0,1]$ such that $S$ is closed and nowhere dense in $\Bbb R$ and such that the Lebesgue measure $m( S)$ is positive. (E.g. $S$ can be a "fat Cantor set".) Let $f(x)=x$ for $x<0$ and let $f(x)=\int_0^x(1-\chi_S(t))dt$ for $x\geq 0.$ So for $x\geq 0$ we have $f(x)=m([0,x] \setminus S).$